# How to resolve Failed to create the part's controls in Eclipse Modeling Persective?

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-sirius

I am creating an ECore Modeling Project in eclipse. As soon as the project is created, I get the following error in the Model Perspective:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: org.eclipse.swt.layout.GridData cannot be cast to org.eclipse.swt.layout.FillData
```

> Failed to create the part's controls

[image: See log]

I have the latest build of the Eclipse framework:

```
eclipse.buildId=4.9.0.I20180906-0745
java.version=1.8.0_161
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That looks like Eclipse bug [540039](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=540039) a duplicate of [539333](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=539333).

This is marked as fixed in Eclipse Sirius 6.0.2